# tcolorbox generates errors when included

Tags: tcolorbox, compilation-error

I'm having a small problem since my computer was reinstalled by the IT of my office. The package tcolorbox which used to work can't be included anymore.

MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This code generates multiple errors, first of which is `Undefined control sequence : \ExplSyntaxOn` . Does someone have an idea what's wrong ?

I'm compiling using XeLaTex, on texmaker 5.1.2 on windows 10. Latex and PDFlatex generate the same error.

Comment: Show the log-file, but my guess that have an old latex and a new tcolorbox.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but I can't attach a file to a post can I ? How do I post the whole logfile ?

Comment: @CyrilDevanthery The log file is a text file, just copy-paste it in your question as it was code.